# Undefined procedure DWIM could not correct the goal in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm really new to prolog and I'm trying out some examples.
I'm getting the error

`ERROR: Undefined procedure: eats/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)` when I run the rule.

Why is it showing if my rule is true? Please see rule below from my .pl file. This is taken from an example.

```
eats(fred,oranges).                           /* "Fred eats oranges" */
```

Prolog command consult: `eats(fred,oranges).`

Any explanation for this error would be very helpful.

Comment: Carried out some more troubleshooting, might have been .pl file not loaded correctly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, so probably it didn't get consulted properly.

Comment: Were you able to figure out your problem?

Comment: @DanielLyons yes I'm just back on it now. Moving onto recursion and lists. I had to click 'File' > 'Reload modified files'. It also works by re-consulting the .pl program. Thanks for your help it's great!

Answer (score 0):

> The FAQ says it all: http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.html
>
> You need to create a file and write your program with rules there. The
> top level command line will only allow you to issue queries.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404259/1599699

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the command you can resolve the issue by a simple command go to compile< compile buffer or use shortcut key control-c control-b. This will surely make your code run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).