# Unable to create Fact in Jekejeke Prolog

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, prolog-assert, jekejeke

I'm using the Seven Languages In Seven Weeks Prolog tutorial and trying to run through some examples using the Android Jekejeke Runtime.
For example, if I add

```
likes(wallace, grommit).
```

from the tutorial, I get.

```
Error: Undefined, private or package local predicate likes/2
```

I tried using assert, as described in [How to create a fact in SWI-Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084427/how-to-create-a-fact-in-swi-prolog), but then it says that `assert` is undefined, instead of likes.

Presumably I'm missing something basic about how the runtime works, or its dialect of prolog.it.

Comment: Jekejeke is right. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20027252/772868) why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assert/1` is not a standard predicate, although several implementations provide it. That doesn't seem to be the case for Jekejeke Prolog. Use instead either the `asserta/1` or the `assertz/1` standard predicates. The first asserts a clause as the first for the predicate. The latter asserts a clause as the last for the predicate.

Comment: And I need to use them to assert a fact? The Seven Languages tutorial has skipped over that so far, if you do

Comment: Depends on exactly what you mean "to assert a fact". Predicate definitions are usually defined in a source file that you compile and load. The assert predicates are used when adding clauses for *dynamic*  predicates at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error. Namely that there is a certain assumption
that facts can be entered in the top level directly by typing it.

The interpreter issues an error since he understands what is input as a query and the predicate in the query is yet undefined.

But the end-user has multiple options:

**1) First option use assertz/1 or asserta/1:**
The top level is for executing goals. You need a goal that instructs interpreter to perform an assert. Use asserta/1 or assertz/1:

Top-level:

```
?- assertz(likes(foo, bar)).
```

Please not that predicates that have already been used as a static predicate, i.e. have been added by method 2) or 3), cannot be anymore asserted. Use the dynamic/1 directive then.

The built-in assert/1 is not supported since it is not part of the ISO core standard and usually redundant to assertz/1.

**2) Second option use a file and consult it:**
Place the facts and rules into a file. And consult it via the consult/1 built-in.

File baz.p:

```
likes(foo, bar).
```

Top-level:

```
?- consult('baz.p').
```

Instead of consult/1 you can also use ensure_loaded/1 or use_module/1.

**3) Third option directly consult from console:**
Enter the facts and rules directly in the top-level. Finish your entering of facts and rules by the end-of-file key stroke.

Top-level:

```
?- [user].
likes(foo, bar).
^D
```

Bye

Comment: See also https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_%28Programmiersprache%29#Laden_von_Prolog-Texten